# How to make alert box and innerHTML show in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, innerhtml

I'm trying to make a salary calculator with a simple javascript field validator. However, when I add my conditional if statements they seem to cancel each other out. I'm not sure if I need to make another function to make this happen.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("payrate").value;
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours").value;
    var salary;


    salary = rate * hours;
    if (hours == ' '){
        alert("Fill hours");
    else if (payrate == ' '){
        alert("Fill payrate");
    }
}

if (salary < 20000) {
    salary = "The salary is too little";   
}else if(salary > 20000 && salary < 25000){
    salary = "Let's negotiate";
} else { 
    salary = "This good salary";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = salary;
}
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
Enter hourly Rate: <input type="text" id="payrate"><br>
Enter hours: <input type="text" id="hours"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Yearly Salary" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: You should learn to use the console to help you debug JavaScript code (https://gyazo.com/a660a26614794aaa7b42a6739b712af2).

Comment: Consider using `isNaN()` and `trim()` too.

Comment: I doubt the value will be equal to `" "` and you are not going the salary check inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 issues here:

1. Your brackets are not closed correctly.
2. You declare a variable name `rate` but you check a variable name `payrate`.
3. Your logic is not good. You should validate data first, then do the calculation.
4. The way you check for empty string should be changed. You have a space when checking for empty string (`' '`). It will lead to wrong result. `''` should be used instead. However, I suggest another way in my code.

So, the new code is:

```
function myFunction() {
    var rate = document.getElementById("payrate").value;
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours").value;
    var salary;

    // Validate data first
    if (!hours) {
        alert("Fill hours");

        // Stop the execution
        return false;
    } else if (!rate) {
        alert("Fill payrate");

        // Stop the execution
        return false;
    }
    salary = rate * hours;

    if (salary < 20000) {
        salary = "The salary is too little";
    } else if (salary > 20000 && salary < 25000) {
        salary = "Let's negotiate";
    } else {
        salary = "This good salary";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = salary;
}
```

You can test this on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v8q771n/).

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets aren't closed properly.

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
var rate = document.getElementById("payrate").value;
var hours = document.getElementById("hours").value;
var salary;
salary = rate * hours;
if (hours == ' ') {
    alert("Fill hours");
}
else if (payrate == ' ') {
    alert("Fill payrate");
}
if (salary < 20000) {
    salary = "The salary is too little";   
} else if(salary > 20000 && salary < 25000){
    salary = "Let's negotiate";
} else { 
    salary = "This good salary";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is bad and the brackets aren't closed properly try this:

```
function myFunction() {
var rate = document.getElementById("payrate").value;
var hours = document.getElementById("hours").value;
var salary;

salary = rate * hours;

//With out reurn false; the flow will still continue and return an value in the demo
   // and also check for if hours is a number

if (hours === '' || isNaN(hours)){
alert("Fill hours");
    return false;
}


//With out reurn false; the flow will still continue and return an value in the demo
   // and also check for if payrateis a number.

if (payrate === '' || isNaN(payrate) ){
alert("Fill payrate");
    return false;
}

 if (salary < 20000) {
 salary = "The salary is too little";   
}else if(salary > 20000 && salary < 25000){
  salary = "Let's negotiate";
  } else { 
 salary = "This good salary";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 'if' statements, you have code like `salary = "The salary is too little"`. Maybe you meant to do something like `console.log("The salary is too little")`? Or you could use an alert instead of console.log. Hope that works.